# Can not get socket to stay alive and receive data

Tags: c, sockets, select, posix

I want to use this socket to open on connection, `Fork` it and stay open until the connection is terminated by me or the client program.

At the moment I can only get it to open and then receive one message and close right afterwards OR remain open but not retrieve any data for reasons I do not know.

The code below is largely the tutorials but the end I tried to make while loops to read the select function until a message is ready to be read. Then I just want it to print that string when it receives it and to not close.

I have been messing about with this code and I am really tired so sorry if I messed something up.

Is there a way I can make the `Fork` function I created to have a while(1) loop inside that just check the socket for received messages?

```
void *socket_handler_thread(void *x_void_ptr)
{
  int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
  socklen_t sin_size;
  struct sigaction sa;
  int yes = 1;
  char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  int rv;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

  if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));

  }

// loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
  for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
  {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
    {
      perror("server: socket");
      continue;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
      perror("setsockopt");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
    {
      close(sockfd);
      perror("server: bind");
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

  if (p == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
  {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
  if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1)
  {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

  int socket_fd, result;
  fd_set readset;
  struct timeval tv;
  /* Wait up to five seconds. */
  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = 100000;

  while (1)
  {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &sin_size);

    if (new_fd == -1)
    {
      perror("accept");
      continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *) &their_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    do
    {

      FD_ZERO(&readset);
      FD_SET(new_fd, &readset);
      result = select(new_fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
      printf("Stuck result = %i  ::: new_fd = %i \n\r", result, new_fd);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    if (result > 0)
    {
      if (FD_ISSET(new_fd, &readset))
      {
        if (!fork())
        { // this is the child process

          printf("WORKED!");

          Fork(sockfd, new_fd);

        }
        //close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
      }

      result = recv(socket_fd, some_buffer, some_length, 0);
      if (result == 0)
      {
        /* This means the other side closed the socket */
        //close(socket_fd);
      }
      else
      {
        /* I leave this part to your own implementation */
      }

    }
    else if (result < 0)
    {
      printf("Connection closed!");
      /* An error ocurred, just print it to stdout */
    }
  }

}

void Fork(int sockfd, int new_fd)
{
  int n;
  char buffer[256];
  bzero(buffer, 256);

  close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
  if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("send");
  }

  n = read(new_fd, buffer, 255);
  if (n > 0)
  {
    printf("NOW-> %i  ::: %s", n, buffer);
  }

  close(new_fd);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: **which** tutorials?

Comment: C is case sensitive, so `fork` isn't `Fork` isn't `FORK`. Your naming is highly confusing. Also, this is by no means a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: Format and indent your code properly! This mess is unreadable. Also be more specific and provide a [mcve]

Comment: "*I am really tired*" then have a sleep, and tomorrow go over the code from today understand it, think about what it does. Be you own reviewer.

Comment: `fork()` is a well known system function.   1) do not create functions with the same name as the system functions.   2) do not separate names by only capitalization as that can be very confusing to the human reader of the code.

Comment: The code does not compile.

Answer (score -1):

to keep a socket connection open:

use the setsockopt() function with the 'keepalive' option

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name,
    const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len);

SO_KEEPALIVE
Keeps connections active by enabling the periodic transmission of messages, if this is supported by the protocol. 
This option takes an int value.

Return Value

Upon successful completion, setsockopt() shall return 0. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.
```

Here is one example

```
int on = 1;
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
{ // then setsockopt failed
    perror( "setsockopt failed for SO_KEEPALIVE" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

here is a quote from: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html about the keepalive setsockopt()

begin quote:
*"2.4. Preventing disconnection due to network inactivity
The other useful goal of keepalive is to prevent inactivity from disconnecting the channel. It's a very common issue, when you are behind a NAT proxy or a firewall, to be disconnected without a reason. This behavior is caused by the connection tracking procedures implemented in proxies and firewalls, which keep track of all connections that pass through them. Because of the physical limits of these machines, they can only keep a finite number of connections in their memory. The most common and logical policy is to keep newest connections and to discard old and inactive connections first.
Returning to Peers A and B, reconnect them. Once the channel is open, wait until an event occurs and then communicate this to the other peer. What if the event verifies after a long period of time? Our connection has its scope, but it's unknown to the proxy. So when we finally send data, the proxy isn't able to correctly handle it, and the connection breaks up.
Because the normal implementation puts the connection at the top of the list when one of its packets arrives and selects the last connection in the queue when it needs to eliminate an entry, periodically sending packets over the network is a good way to always be in a polar position with a minor risk of deletion. "*
end quote:

Comment: This does not help the OP at all.

Comment: @alk, the OP ask how to keep the connection/socket open.  The SO_KEEPALIVE is *exactly* the method for keeping a socket open across several 'messages'.

Comment: Under "normal" circumstances a TCP socket connection only gets closed if the sender or the receiver explicitly shuts it down or closes it, no matter if data is sent across it or not. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html